# Session_unset and session_destroy not working

Tags: php, session

Was just wondering why my code isn't working here:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION)) {
      session_unset();
      session_destroy();
    }
?>
```

I've tried printing out the result of echo isset($_SESSION) and it returns true, and my pages that require login are still allowing me to access them.

Comment: I've tried printing out the result of echo isset($_SESSION) and it returns true, and my pages that require login are still allowing me to access them.

Comment: Dont check for login status simply by doing `isset($_SESSION)`, check for a specific var.

Comment: I checked for the session variable and it seems to not exist, however, my pages which require a login can still be accessed. However, I do use `if (!(isset($_SESSION)))` on that page with a header to return to login, is this the issue?

Comment: It depends if you're starting the session before. Though you should be checking for specific vars which wont be there if you sign out the user.

Comment: Checking the specific variables for the session has worked, thanks for your help!

Comment: np, ive countered that downvote, happy coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must definitely define a variable as session

for example:

**LOGIN**

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_POST['username']){
$_SESSION['username'] =$_POST['username']; // session run
}
?>
```

**LOGOUT**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_POST['LOGOUT']=='exit'){
@session_unset();
    }
    ?>
```

You can also use 
unset($_SESSION['username']); 
instead of 
session_unset();